# Center align a modal popup of larger than default width using default Twitter Bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In Twitter Bootstrap, the default width of a modal popup is 560px and `left` is 50%. I want the modal popup to be larger width. So, I added the class `span10` to the modal popup. But as the `left` is fixed to 50%, the modal popup goes to the right. To fix this, I added `left: 8%` as inline CSS to the modal popup. It works as I intended. But I want to know whether is there any trick to do this with default CSS of Twitter Bootstrap and not using any extra CSS (inline, internal or external).

Answer (score 10):

Using Bootstrap 2.2, I added a CSS selector to the `modal` container and setting the `width` and `margin-left` to `width`/2 * -1.

Example:

```
#MyModal {
   width: 900px; 
   margin-left: -450px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="MyModal" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog">
  <!-- etc. -->
</div>
```

---

**Edit**

Bootstrap does not currently have a way, through the JS or data-role behaviors to customize a modal's width. If you wanted a new default width globally, you'll either have to fork bootstrap and modify their LESS templates, edit the compiled CSS, or add CSS to your own stylesheet with a selector similar to how I've described and include it after bootstrap.css in your pages. The latter is the easiest.

Alternatively, if you want to retain the default width but pre-defined a few typical modal sizes, you could just add a few class selectors in your own style sheet and add the class names as needed.

```
.modal-small { width: 200px; margin-left: -100px; }
.modal-large { width: 900px; margin-left: -450px; }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="modal modal-large hide fade" /> <!-- make this one large -->
 <div class="modal modal-small hide fade" /> <!-- and this one small -->
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know this is a good solution. But I am interested to solve this problem without using any extra CSS. I want to know whether it's possible to achieve using default CSS of Twitter Bootstrap only.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. Unfortunately, they do not currently have a setting or what have you for setting the width. To make this change globally, you'd either have to fork the bootstrap source and add make the changes yourself, or just include a stylesheet after the prebuilt bootstrap.css with CSS similar to above on your page.